# Is “serves” a verb or noun in this complex sentence? (“...and serves as a tool for communication...“)

Tags: american-english, translation

> Project scheduling provides a detailed plan that represents how and when the project will deliver the products,
>   services, and results defined in the project scope and serves as a tool for communication, managing stakeholders’
>   expectations, and as a basis for performance reporting.

In the above sentence, is the word *serves* a verb or a noun?

And how can I understand the whole sentence? Project scheduling provides a detailed plan and serves (NOUN). Is it correct?
or  Project scheduling provides a detailed plan and serves as tool...(If it is VERB).

Comment: "Project scheduling provides a detailed plan that represents how and when the project will deliver the products, services, and results defined in the project scope. It also [serves as] [/is] a tool for communication & managing stakeholders’ expectations, _and_ it serves as a basis for performance reporting." //// Please note that ELU does  _not_  offer an interpretation / comprehension service. 'In the above sentence, is "serves" a verb or noun?' would be a valid question on our sister site, ELL, though they probably expect some signs of research (a dictionary definition, at least).

Comment: *Project scheduling **provides** [a plan] AND [Project scheduling] **serves as** [a tool]*. But it might help parsing if the writer included a comma after that AND.

Comment: _Serve_ as a noun is very rare except in tennis.

Answer (score 1):

If the question about 'complex sentence' expects a syntactical reply, "A complex sentence has a main clause and one or more dependent clause(s).

E.g. Project scheduling provides a detailed plan that represents how and when the project will deliver the products, services, and results.  Here "Project scheduling provides a detailed plan" is the main clause.

"that represents 'how and when the project will deliver the products, services, and results'  " is a dependent clause which cannot stand alone. It is like....

...that represents a chain of things
...that represents a set of things... Similarly,
...that represents how and when the project will deliver the products, services, and results

Serves - is a verb.
... serves as a tool for communication, managing stakeholders’ expectations, and 
as a basis for performance reporting.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence means

> Project planning provides a detailed plan that does two things. It details how and when the project will deliver its results. It also serves as a tool for communicating, managing expectations and measuring performance.

Trying to cram all that into one sentence is apt to lead to a sentence that is hard to understand. Here the failure to seperate "results and serves" where "result" is used as a noun and "serves" is used as a verb, into "... results and that serves" or into "... results, and (2) that serves" is an open invitation to confusion. The sentence is grammatical but awkward. A good writer could make the intent clear in a single sentence, but it is easy to convey the intended thought clearly in several sentences.